# Reactivity in the pagination component does not occur

Tags: flutter, dart, pagination, widget

I am facing the following situation:

I created the component below that generates the pagination of my data:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

The code that creates this component is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PaginationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PaginationWidget({
    required this.listCount,
    required this.onSelectCallback,
    required this.page,
    super.key,
    this.selectionColor,
    this.notSelectedColor,
    this.arrowsColor,
    this.size = 32.0,
  });

  final int listCount;
  final int page;
  final void Function(int pageNumber) onSelectCallback;
  final double size;
  final Color? selectionColor;
  final Color? notSelectedColor;
  final Color? arrowsColor;

  @override
  State<PaginationWidget> createState() =>
      _PaginationWidgetState();
}

class _PaginationWidgetState
    extends State<PaginationWidget> {
  final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

  int selectedPage = 1;

  double _transformSize(double size) {
    return (widget.size * size) / 44.0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const int itemCount = 5;

    final Color selectionColor =
        widget.selectionColor ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

    final Color notSelectedColor = widget.notSelectedColor ??
        Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.3);

    final Color arrowsColor =
        widget.arrowsColor ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    return SizedBox(
      height: _transformSize(44),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ///Last index button
          AbsorbPointer(
            absorbing: selectedPage <= 1,
            child: IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              hoverColor: Theme.of(context).hoverColor,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedPage -= 1;
                });
                widget.onSelectCallback(selectedPage);

                _controller.animateTo(
                  ((selectedPage - 1) / itemCount) * _transformSize(259.9),
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  curve: Curves.linear,
                );
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
                color: (selectedPage > 1)
                    ? arrowsColor
                    : Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),

          /// Numbers row

          Container(
            width: widget.listCount > itemCount ? _transformSize(290) : null,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _transformSize(18)),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _controller,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: List.generate(widget.listCount, (index) {
                  final int pageNumber = index + 1;
                  return Padding(
                    padding: widget.listCount - pageNumber > 0
                        ? EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: _transformSize(8))
                        : EdgeInsets.zero,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      child: NumberButton(
                        onTap: () {
                          if (pageNumber != selectedPage) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedPage = pageNumber;
                            });
                            widget.onSelectCallback(pageNumber);
                          }
                        },
                        buttonText: (pageNumber).toString(),
                        isSelected: selectedPage == pageNumber,
                        size: widget.size,
                        selectionColor: selectionColor,
                        notSelectedColor: notSelectedColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          ///Next index button
          AbsorbPointer(
            absorbing: selectedPage >= widget.listCount,
            child: IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              hoverColor: Theme.of(context).hoverColor,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedPage += 1;
                });
                widget.onSelectCallback(selectedPage);
                if ((selectedPage - 1) % itemCount == 0) {
                  _controller.animateTo(
                    ((selectedPage - 1) / itemCount) * _transformSize(259.9),
                    duration: const Duration(microseconds: 1),
                    curve: Curves.linear,
                  );
                }
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined,
                color: (selectedPage < widget.listCount)
                    ? arrowsColor
                    : Theme.of(context).disabledColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const NumberButton({
    required this.buttonText,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.size,
    required this.selectionColor,
    required this.notSelectedColor,
    super.key,
  });

  final String buttonText;
  final void Function() onTap;
  final bool isSelected;
  final double size;
  final Color selectionColor;
  final Color notSelectedColor;

  double _transformSize(double size) {
    return (this.size * size) / 44.0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        height: _transformSize(44),
        width: _transformSize(44),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isSelected ? selectionColor : notSelectedColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_transformSize(8)),
        ),
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            buttonText,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: _transformSize(18),
              color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This component is called on my screen as below:

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.end,
   children: [
        PaginationWidget(
           listCount: state.content.totalPages,
           page: state.content.page,
           selectionColor:const Color(0xff003886),
           arrowsColor: Colors.black,
           notSelectedColor: const Color(0xffFFFFFF),
           onSelectCallback:(int pageNumber) {
               controller.fetchBusinessMovements(
                   transactionStartDate:selectedDateRange.startDate,
                   transactionEndDate:selectedDateRange.endDate,
                   page: pageNumber - 1,
                   vision: businessVisionTType.value.type,
            );
         },
      ),
   ],
 ),
```

The problem I am facing is the following:

When I call my controller (my API call) in onSelectCallback the component simply hangs, reactivity in the component does not occur, that is, the pagination hangs does not advance or retreat.

However, if I remove my API call, the component responds normally again.

I know this is a classic reactivity problem, but I'm not able to solve it.

What I've already done:

- I forced the component to rebuild using a UniqueKey().
- I wrapped the component with a Builder, to force it to update.

None of this works.

Can anyone help me with this problem??